# List Definition and List Instance in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list-definition

What is List Definition and List Instance in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 5):

List definitions provide a template for you to create lists from.

A List Instance is a single "instance" of a list created from an aforementioned list definition. A List instance can also be instantiated with data.

Comment: And it's worth noting that a list definition can be used by multiple list instances. It's sort of like the difference between a class, and an object in c#

Comment: Indeed, also not that in Visual Studio 2010, List Instances are NOT torn down when you stop debugging, and VS retracts your solution.